2024 Moderator Election Q&A – Question Collection

The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it here.


Islam Stack Exchange is scheduled for an election next week, 2024-10-29. In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.
Here’s how it’ll work:

Until the nomination phase, (so, until 2024-10-29 at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post one question per answer.

If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of [text](link), as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.

This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into currently.

We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The following two questions are guaranteed to be included:

How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc. a question that you feel shouldn’t have been?


The community team may also include the following three questions if the community doesn’t supply enough questions.

In your opinion, what do moderators do?
A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching enough reputation to access moderator tools or become a trusted user?


At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. We exclude any suggested questions that are negatively scored.

We will post the final questionnaire on the Election page. Candidates will have the option to fill out the questionnaire, and their answers will appear beneath their intro statements.
This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.



If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

While Islam Stack Exchange has always had fairly regular activity on the main site, there has been little to no engagement with the Chat or Meta sides of things. Do you feel this is a concern, and if so, how do you hope to improve the situation as a moderator?

Often, questions are asked regarding sensitive topics where traditional Islamic views are in direct opposition to modern sensibilities, for example regarding slavery or LGBTQ rights, and honest answers to these questions may offend people or fall afoul of the Stack Exchange Code of Conduct. If one of these is flagged for moderator attention, how would you handle it?

Religious sites often attract argument and debate, and can devolve into spreading specious arguments and even outright lies to discredit other points of view. This misinformation can often be hard to recognize if you don't have expertise in all sides of the argument. While moderators are not expected to have domain expertise in all Islamic topics, they are expected to enforce the Code of Conduct and as such may need to deal with flags of this nature. How would you judge whether a flagged post is actually willful misinformation vs just being a technically incorrect answer?

I don't fully understand this question. Are you asking how would one judge whether false information was given intentionally or due to an honest mistake? I mean wouldn't false information that is harmful be removed regardless of that?

@UmH It's more about how you would handle a situation where you don't know enough about the topic to really know whether or not it's even harmful in the first place, vs just a harmless mistake.

From time to time our site attracts some users who like to see their interpretation of Islam as the only truth and challenge this with appropriate answers or questions that make other views appear in a rather questionable light.
How would you deal with this as a moderator?

Questions are asked again and again on this site that make you think that this is one of the basics that everyone should know about Islam. Couldn't this person have researched this themselves? Perhaps also in the category of "these are topics that every Muslim should know?" How would you deal with these questions? For example, would you differentiate whether the person asking the question says they are a Muslim, a convert, or not a Muslim?
